# addition and multiplication of functions in function space, continuous?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity, normed-spaces

I have a norm that works in function space of C[0,1]. How do I show that addition and multiplication of functions (C[0,1]xC[0,1]->C[0,1]) are continuous functions?

Comment: Since you know that $C[0,1]$ is normed, one might take sequences $f_n\to f$, $g_n\to g$, and show that $f_n+g_n\to f+g$ and $f_n\cdot g_n\to f\cdot g$.

Answer (score 0):

- To use `C[0,1]` to show continuity within Function Composition you will have to take into consideration only a few concepts for concluding that `(C[0,1]xC[0,1]->C[0,1])` can create a paradigm for continuous functions [within structures].
- We will assume that `C[0,1]` can become a Function of Several Real Variables by using a seminorm. In a Euclidean norm Vector spaces must be allowed to use `(0,0)` for magnitude within any cartesian. So, we have precedent for understanding how norms can function as both zero vector spaces, by using `(0,1)` you actually solve your own problem by assigning an Integer [at least 1].

1. Proving Continuity and Limit:

   - Consider the distance function of `ℝᵤ`, where

> `C[0,1] ≐ d ≑ d(x,y)=d(x₁,…,xᵤ,y₁,...yᵤ)= √((x₁-y₁)²+…+(xᵤ-yᵤ)²)`
>
> > Proving Continuity and Limit:
> >
> > > consider the function `ƒ` in `C[0,1]` such that `ƒ(0,0)=0` is otherwise defined by
> > >       `ƒ(x,y)=x²y/x²*²+y²`
> > >
> > > > The functions
> > > >          `x→C(x,0)`
> > > >  
> > > >          and
> > > >  
> > > >          `y→C(0,y)`
> > > >  
> > > >         are both constant and equal to zero, and are therefore continuous
> > > >
> > > > Providing `C[0,1]` as a seminorm and concluding its use for Functional Continuity :
> > > >
> > > > - For every real number
> > > >
> > > > > `ε > 0` and `δ > 0`
> > > > >  
> > > > >                    such that
> > > > >                   `∣ƒ(x)—L<ε∣`
> > > > >           `x` evaluates in its domain as
> > > > >                `d(x,a) < δ`
> > > > >
> > > > > > If the limit exists, it is unique.
> > > > > >  
> > > > > >             If `a` is in the interior of the domain:
> > > > > >  
> > > > > >             The limit exists if and only if the function is continuous at `a`
> > > > > >             For our instance
> > > > > >             `ƒ(a)=lim┬(x→a)  ƒ(x)`
> > > > > >
> > > > > > When `a` is in the boundary of the domain of `f`
> > > > > >
> > > > > > > `f` has a limit at `a`
> > > > > > >                the latter formula allows the extension of continuity
> > > > > > >
> > > > > > > > which essentially is the domain of
> > > > > > > >
> > > > > > > > > `f` to `a`
> > > > > > > > >
> > > > > > > > > > So since the seminorm `C[0,1]` can accommodate a series of functions, such as;
> > > > > > > > > >  
> > > > > > > > > >                     `C(x,y)=C(x,y)=C(x₁,…,xᵤ,y₁,...yᵤ)= √((x₁-y₁)²+…+(xᵤ-yᵤ)²)`
> > > > > > > > > >
> > > > > > > > > > > > On another note, I believe that Functional Composition can restate:
> > > > > > > > > > > >  
> > > > > > > > > > > >                         `ξ : X→Ξ`
> > > > > > > > > > > >  
> > > > > > > > > > > >                         `ζ : Ξ→ℝ`